# Keycloak policy enforcer bearer-only client

Tags: node.js, keycloak

I am developing a Node.js web app that uses Keycloak as authentication service. I already have two clients: `public` client for the web app (app-web) and `bearer-only` for the API (app-api). On the app-api I use resources, scopes, policies, and permissions to control the access.

To check the permissions, I am using the `keycloak.enforcer(...)` from the `keycloak-connect` module ([npm keycloak-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-connect)). When I try to check permission, the server always returns `403 Access denied` response. But if I change app-api from `bearer-only` to confidential (keeping the same `keycloak.json` configuration file), the client works fine and is capable to check permissions.

This problem seems to be because a `bearer-only` client cannot obtain tokens from the server ([keycloak similar question](http://keycloak-user.88327.x6.nabble.com/keycloak-user-can-we-use-authorization-with-bearer-only-td2123.html)).

My question is: Is this a normal behavior of Keycloak? Why allow the `Authorization` tab in `bearer-only` clients if you cannot use the `keycloak.enforcer`? Am I missing some configuration?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also stumbled over this bearer-only thing a few days ago. And I also found it confusing that you can enable fine grained authorization, it took me some time to find that out too. Well, a bearer-only client, as the name already states, authenticates clients only by their bearer token.

Comment: Yes, a `bearer-only` client is only to authenticate. If you need authorization too, you need to set your client as `confidential` and use it as `bearer-only: true` on your `keycloak.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question to the Keycloak mailing list too and the answer was:

> *It is the expected behavior but also a UI issue. You should not have access to that tab when the client is bearer-only.*

They even create an issue [KEYCLOAK-10808](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-10808)

This is similar to what @Valentin mention.

If you want to read all the thread: [Mailing list response](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2019-July/018689.html)